# How to change language using uft8 in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How to change language using uft8 but I tried and couldn't.

```
Future fetchMos() async {
String mosUrl = ();
var url = Uri.parse(mosUrl);
var headers = {'Client-Token': 'p'};
var response = await client.get(url, headers: headers);
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  var items = json.decode(response.body)['items'];

  print(items);
  setState(() {
    mos = items;
  });
} else {
  mos = [];
}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it looks like the issue is from server side!

check your backend side headers they should support UTF-8

if you're using PHP add this to your connection headers

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

and if you're using PDO to connect to DB user this array as options

```
$option = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES UTF-8"
```